# get checkbox and radio button value in lift

Tags: forms, scala, checkbox, radio-button, lift

i am trying to processing a form in lift frame work. my form is having one checkbox and radiobuttons. how could i check whether the checkbox is checked or not and the selected radio button.the following code i used to get other elements value.

the view:

```
<form class="lift:MySnippet?form=post">
 From:<input type="text" name="source" /><br />
 To:  <input type="text" name="destination" /><br />
 Age: <input type="text" name = "age"/><br />
 Return: <input type="checkbox" name="needreturn" value="Return Ticket" /><br />
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />Male<br />
 <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" />Female<br />
 <input type="submit" value="Book Ticket"/>
</form>
```

and MySnippet scala code is:

```
  object MySnippet {
     def render = {
             var from = ""
             var to = ""
             var age = 0

            def process() {
                S.notice("in process function")
            }

     "name=source" #> SHtml.onSubmit(from = _) &
     "name=destination" #> SHtml.onSubmit(to = _) &
     "name=age" #> SHtml.onSubmit(s => asInt(s).foreach(age = _)) &
     "type=submit" #> SHtml.onSubmitUnit(process)        
   }
  }
```

in this how could i process the checkbox and radio button. can anyone help me...thanx in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need to specify the choices in your HTML? If not, the easiest way is:

```
Return: <input type="checkbox" name="needreturn" /><br />
Sex: <input type="radio" name="sex" />
```

and the CSS Transform:

```
val radioChoices = List("male", "female")
var sex:Box[String] = None
var needReturn:Boolean = false

"@sex" #> SHtml.radio(radioChoices, sex, (resp) => sex = Full(resp)) &
"@needreturn" #> SHtml.checkbox(needReturn, (resp) => needReturn = resp)
```

You could replace `SHtml.radio` with `SHtml.ajaxRadio` and `SHtml.checkbox` with `SHtml.ajaxCheckbox` if you want your selection to be sent to the server every time the value is changed, instead of when the form is submitted

I believe you can also use the `SHtml.onSubmit` as you do above for the checkbox and radio, but I'd have to do some testing to figure out exactly how.

With regards to the radio button, you can find some information about changing the way the label is output here if you need to: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/liftweb/rowpmIDbQAE

Comment: I tried this. but the needReturn value is not changing if i check checkbox. and could you plz tel me what is the resp means.

Comment: `resp` is just the name I gave the variable (short for response). It is just a function that takes a single parameter, and returns `Unit`. Similar to how you use `s` in your example, or equivalently `needReturn = _`.

Comment: so we are saving the response in the needReturn variable. but why it is not getting exactly. if i checked the checkbox also it's showing false value (i just printed it using S.notice).

Comment: I would check the HTML, is it possible that you have two fields with the `name=needreturn`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `SHtml.checkbox`, `SHtml.radio`

By the way, the `<input>-s` should be `SHtml.text`, I think. So, they're not buttons -- they're inputs. Don't forget to check the resulting html in the web page with firebug. (You'd see that using the current code you have `input=text` deleted.)

Comment: can you help me by showing an example..because i noticed the SHtml.checkBox function before.. but its more than one..so which one i should take..and i didnt understand about the parameters..

Comment: There is a demo application here:
http://demo.liftweb.net/
Basically, "ajax" methods send you what the user types in before submitting the form. Other differences between these methods can be seen from the method signatures. And by jumping into the code, if you use an IDE.

If you have questions about checkboxes and ajax in general -- you should read about html <input> and <form> in general.