# Radio button in Lift?

Tags: scala, radio-button, lift

I'm trying to render a radio button choice in my webapp but I have some problems.

What I have done is to try jcern solution posted in this answer:
[get checkbox and radio button value in lift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879991/get-checkbox-and-radio-button-value-in-lift)

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="lift:Radio.render">
   <input id="choice" name="choice" type="radio"/>
</div>
```

And this is my SCALA code:

```
object Radio {
  def render = {
    val radioChoices = List("Choice_1", "Choice_2")
    var choice:Box[String] = None

    "name=choice" #> SHtml.radio(radioChoices, choice, (resp) => choice = Full(resp))
  }
}
```

But the compiler give me an error on binding:

```
could not find implicit value for parameter computer:net.liftweb.util.CanBind[net.liftweb.http.SHtml.ChoiceHolder[String]]
[error]   "@choice" #> SHtml.radio(radioChoices, choice, (resp) => choice = Full(resp))
[error]             ^
```

I have to bind with `.toForm` to pass compile like this:

```
"name=choice" #> SHtml.radio(radioChoices, choice, (resp) => choice = Full(resp)).toForm
```

The problem is that no radio buttons are displayed on my web page, nothing at all..

Am I doing something wrong? I can't see it. And why the first solution (without `.toForm`) give me an error at compile?

Comment: Solved this issue.. I was editing html file in the 'taget/webapp/' folder instaead of 'main/webapp/'. The code posted above it's working fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `SHtml.radio` and `SHtml.radioElem` return a `ChoiceHolder` instead of a the `NodeSeq` that most other items in `SHtml` do - as you can see in the [API Doc](http://liftweb.net/api/25/api/#net.liftweb.http.SHtml). Because of that, you need to call `.toForm` or render the output yourself.

Returning the `ChoiceHolder` allows you to customize how each item is displayed, so you can add custom text for the label, etc... If the basic `toForm` output didn't work for you, you could do something like:

```
val choices =  SHtml.radio(radioChoices, choice, (resp) => choice = Full(resp))
"@choice" #> choices.items.zipWithIndex.map { case(itm, pos) =>
  val rId = "myId-%s".format(pos)
  <div class="radio">{ 
      //We'll add a custom ID attribute to the radio button
      itm.xhtml.asInstanceOf[Elem] % ("id", rId) 
    }<label for={ rId }>{
      //Output the toString or use some other method to output a label 
      itm.toString  
    }</label>
  </div>
}
```

You can find more information on customizing the radio buttons in the [Lift Cookbook](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#Radio).

As for why your `CSSSelector` is not outputing anything, I am not sure. The code snippet you were trying worked for me. The screenshot below illustrates the output I see with the `toForm` method.

[image: Screen shot of output]

Comment: thanks jcern, I'really don't get why my code doesn't work for me.. I'm trying yours but it gives me also an error: 
in line '}<label for={ rId }>{' compiler says: 'not found: value rId'
but value rId is declared two lines above.. it's because of the braces? It shouldn't..

Comment: Sorry about that, I moved the declaration for `rId` up. That should make it accessible.

Comment: Oh right, thx I'm gonna try this tomorrow morning, hope it works

Comment: Solved this issue.. I was editing my .html file in the 'target/webapp' folder instead of 'main/webapp', what an i***t..
However your answers are always interesting. Thank you!